# How do I subscribe someone to a list using the python mailchimp API v2.0?

Tags: python, mailchimp

I want to subscribe a user to a list using the [Mailchimp API 2.0](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/) and the [official mailchimp python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailchimp/2.0.9).  I can't find any direct documentation for how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before you start, you'll need to get your API key and the list id by logging into Mailchimp.

To get the API key, visit *Accounts > Extras* and generate an API key.
To get the list id, visit *Lists > My list > Settings > List name and defaults*.

Next, make sure you've installed the mailchimp python package:

```
pip install mailchimp
```

Finally:

```
import mailchimp
API_KEY = 'my-api-key'
LIST_ID = 'my-list-id' 

api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': 'email@example.com'})
```

Comment: Good answer. Just 2 notes to add: 1. by default they send confirmation mails and only add to the list once the user hit the link to confirm (you can disable this behavior with `double_optin=False`). 2. I noticed it takes couple of minutes for the list to update on the web dashboard, so don't be surprise if you try and don't see immediate results. Just wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Does the mailchimp library work on AppEngine? We tried to vendor this in as a third party application but it gives a permission denied error when accessing the Mailchimp service.

Comment: Update 2021, replying to @RonenNess comment, the default behavior of adding a new subscriber to the list is without sending a confirmation (which means `double_optin=False` is by default.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer by seddonym: If you want to add the name or other details of the subscriber you can do that by adding merge_vars to the function call like this:

```
api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': email}, merge_vars={'FNAME':fname,'LNAME':lname})
```

See here for all options: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php